# binary matrix aa (only contain 0, 1), why sum(sum(aa)) isn't equal sum(sum(aa>0))?

Tags: python, boolean, numpy-ndarray

I have a binary mask named crop_mask, which only contains 0 and 1. Why isn't the sum(sum(aa1)) equal sum(sum(aa2)).

aa1 = crop_mask,
aa2 = (aa1>0)

print(sum(sum(aa1)), sum(sum(aa2)))

This might be a minor issue, but I am just so confused now. Thanks for any help. I made a screenshot of the result in the attached figure.

[updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlI2Q.png)

Comment: Hi, please try posting you code as a text. Also, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: How do you know that `aa1` only contains 0 or 1?  Seems like that would be an easy thing to verify.

Comment: In your example, what is `cropmask` exactly, can you please share the code that defines it?

Comment: In particular, what does `aa1 == aa2` return?

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. aa1 == aa2 return all a matrix with all True. Yes, I did verify aa only contains 0 and 1. Please see my updated code screenshot.

Comment: crop_mask is a matrix and read in from a tif image. I do save the crop_mask as *.npy file, but stackoverflow seems not allow me upload file.

Answer (score 1):

By definition the sum should be the same.
The only thing I can thing of is that the dtype of your array (assuming you are using a numpy array) is not int or float.
Did you check that the "True"s in aa2 match the "1" in aa1?

EDIT:
dtype = np.uint8 limits the maximum value of the column sum to 255 (2^8). So the sum(sum(a)) --> sum([0,160,0,...]) (160 is the remainder of 4000/256)

aa0 = aa0.astype(int) will solve your issue

```
a = np.zeros((4000, 4000)).astype(np.uint8)
a[:,1] = 1
a[:,4] = 1

b = (a > 0)

sum(sum(b)) # 8000
sum(sum(a)) # 320

a = a.astype(int)
sum(sum(a)) #8000
```

Comment: Yes, it's not int or float. the data type of the element in crop_mask is numpy.uint8.

Comment: Could you explain why they are different if the dtype is uint8? Thank you.

Comment: I got it, it's because of the uint8. The first sum (column-wise) has a maximum capacity of 2^8 because of the uint8 so your sum is truncated. try changing the dtype of your matrix to simply int  `aa1 = aa1.astype(int)` and it should work

Comment: Would you mind explain the reason here? i still dont get it. I tried the following case, the result all equal 6.  bb1 = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1]])
bb2 = bb1.astype(np.uint8)

print(sum(sum(bb1)), sum(sum(bb2))).  so i don't quite understand it

Comment: This will not show up in small arrays. `uint8` can hold values up to 255, so if the sum in each row is smaller this will not be a problem. If instead of using the  `sum(aa1)` you use `np.sum(aa1, axis=1)` the result will be fine as well, since numpy will handle it correctly, without overflow.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. change the dtype to int and the result is correct now. You saved my day, thank you so much.

Comment: exactly, this is only an issue with large matrices, those whose sum will be bigger than 160  . Please check the edits I made to my answer. I was able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @GIOVANNIQUINONESVALDEZ  Good answer, but `uint8` values go to 255, not 160. See [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote at first with 2^8. However, in the example I provide, which reproduces OPs error, I get a total sum of 160 for column 1 and 4. I am not sure why.

Comment: @GIOVANNIQUINONESVALDEZ This is because the sum of each of the two columns should be 4000, and 4000%256=160.

Comment: Nice discussion! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `cropmask` is indeed a 2-dimensional `ndarray` with only 1s and 0s, this works:

```
import numpy as np

cropmask = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]], np.uint8)
x = (cropmask > 0)

print(sum(sum(cropmask)), sum(sum(x)))
```

Result:

```
6 6
```

The most likely cause here is that you're wrong and your `cropmask` doesn't actually contain only 1s and 0s.

Have you tried:

```
print(sum(sum(np.logical_and((0 != crop_mask), (1 != crop_mask)))))
```

If that comes up greater than 0, there's something else in there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this command and the result is zero.  print(sum(sum(np.logical_or((0 > crop_mask), (1 < crop_mask)))))

Comment: If you check the updated screen link in my post, I wrote a short code to verify it only contains 0 and 1. But the the 0 and 1 are dtype uint8. someone points out this may be the cause, but I don't understand this part.

Comment: Tested this again. print(sum(sum(np.logical_and((0 != crop_mask), (1 != crop_mask))))) the result is 0

Comment: Probably made some bad copy paste decisions, fixed the typos

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem has been solved. Please see GIOVANNI QUINONES VALDEZ's anwser.